Getting an error "Timeout waiting for the first frame when launching an URL" when using Go Router
If I run the below code and navigate to the website's home page then nothing happens (no redirect to the app is offered and there is no error in flutter Run tab). If I go to a webpage in the "/jobs/" directory then no redirect to the app is offered and I get the below error message:
[ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/darwin/ios/framework/Source/FlutterViewController.mm(1871)] Timeout waiting for the first frame when launching an URL.

This is the code:
 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  runApp(MaterialApp.router(routerConfig: router));
}


final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      ),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/jobs/*',
          builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Jobs')),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);


The solution was to clear flutter/bin/cache, clear the iMac Bin (I was down to 15-20GB spare space), delete some other files (I increased free space to about 25GB) turn off the computer and turn on, and run flutter doctor. (There's still a coding error but that is for another question!)
